# Push notification from web application to my mobile app

Tags: rest, web-applications, android, ios, laravel

I want to create a mobile app(iOS and Android) for business need, ex: the business is Health and Beauty. So I need a mobile app for sale some goods and service. However, I need push notification to who is subscribe my topic like, health tips, magazine and new product etc.

So I plan to create:

1. Web application back-end with Laravel to manage CRUD of those data then I will implement RESTful API on my web application to handle data from the mobile app.
2. Create a mobile app to fetch data from web application via RESTful API.

My concern is about notification because the mobile app must request it to the server in every x time that way the server must response a lot of requests.

So do we have another way?

Comment: `My concern is about notification because the mobile app must request it to the server in every x time` this is not how push notifications works. **Push** notifications **aren't pulled**.

Comment: Oh you are right...

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel and there are plenty of solutions out there that makes pushing notifications to mobile devices easier.

I personally would recommend [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/) by Google which will work with both iOS, the Web and Android.

It allows you to register devices and send push notifications using their API and plugins, and best of all it is free.